# Magento realtime data integration

Tags: php, api, magento, plugins, e-commerce

this could possibly be answered somewhere allready, but unfortunately I could not find the answer that would suit me.

The question is, can Magento be used only as a front end E-Commerce platform? That is read product nad customer data from external API, and also submit that data to external API. The trick is that it has to be done in real time, not via sheduled tasks.

If there are any Magento plugins that would allow for this, could someone mention any specific names?

Also, how complicated is adding custom functionality to Magento, without "hacking" the system (Things, like multiple shop branches, product sets, that can be enabled per branch, limiting orders to cetain amount of slots per hour etc.)

Comment: Hi, your question is rather broad and involve a lot of off-topic issues, please give http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic a read - Also _"Also, how complicated is adding custom functionality to Magento, without "hacking" the system"_ entirely depends on how good you are.

Comment: Hi, for the first part, i think the question is quite on-topic. The question is, can Magento sync with external API in real time? For the second part I could have made this more clear. How complicated it is for a person quite experienced with Magento. I am not talking about knowledge side, but actually the systems ability to accept custom small extensions.

Comment: You can find useful stuff if you search "Event Driven Programming with Magento"

Comment: Hi, thnx for the tip, I will look it up

Comment: I use external API to load my products and customer details. Nevertheless, these are created on Magento Backend as well. The products and customer are updated via. cron. The product stock and price are calculated in real time via. SOAP.

Comment: Dear @anz can you share with me or point me in the right direction to achieve what you did on your site?. I want to do something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73007542/magento-2-get-inventory-and-prices-in-real-time-from-third-party-api

Comment: Oh boy, that was a long time ago. We used to get products/prices/inventory update everyday (includes text/prices/pictures based on SKU) at a designated location in the server. We'd run update we wrote to ingest this (integration to create/update products programatically on Magento).We set up unix cron-job to invoke & it would update the backend(db) with new data. The process was slow using the regular Magento flow (it'd take 2+ hours). I did implement using the tool Magmi (direct sql queries), but don't know if it ever got pushed to production. Let me know if I can further answer your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire Magento code base uses the Magento database tables for generating the frontend display, so there isn't really any way around it unless you plan on doing a rewrite on every core model to perform the necessary logic (i.e. fetch from/update external source). Existing solutions to this problem generally use the SOAP API and cron jobs to mirror the data (mapping as necessary to get it between the different structures) on both Magento and whatever external system you're using. You can achieve real-time results using the Magento observer system to send updates to your external system by listening to various model save events, and similarly create a SOAP API call when data is updated on your external system (specific implementation details depend on the system) to keep them in sync in real-time.